# Copy Salesforce Production data to a Sandbox without third party tools/connectors

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am new to Salesforce and got the project of copying prod data to sandbox. 
The question is, how can we insert data from production to another sandbox.

Is it through rest call, if it is so then at destination sandbox as well we need class to listen that rest call. But that is not a requirement, what they want is application should be in production box only and on giving correct creds for destination box, data should be copied from production to destination box.

Please suggest me best ways available in Salesforce to copy data from prod to another sandbox using Apex class and triggers.

Comment: Is there any reason, without comments I got negative feedback ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a middle wear system that you could fire an event to which would then trigger listening sandboxes to pick up the data that you are subscribed to.  You will need to create a RESTFul or Soap service either way, it just depends on if there is an event fired.  I recommend that you broadcast an event so all sandboxes subscribed to that event can pick it up.